# Proof for Sum of Sigma Function

Tags: summation, divisor-sum

How to prove:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sigma(k) = n^2 - \sum_{k=1}^nn\mod k$$

where $\sigma(k)$ is sum of divisors of k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the identity
\begin{align}
n \ \text{mod} \ k = n - k \lfloor \tfrac{n}{k} \rfloor,
\end{align}
one has
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (n \ \text{mod} \ k) =\sum_{k = 1}^{n} n - k \lfloor \tfrac{n}{k} \rfloor = n^{2} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n} k \lfloor \tfrac{n}{k} \rfloor.
\end{align}
Finally, since
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n} k \lfloor \tfrac{n}{k} \rfloor = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sigma(k),
\end{align}
the claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d|k} d = \sum_{d=1}^n\sum_{k=1,d|k}^{n}d = \sum_{d=1}^n d\left\lfloor \frac {n} {d}\right\rfloor$$

Now just prove that $$d\left\lfloor \frac n d\right\rfloor = n-(n\mod d)$$

Comment: You beat me to the punch by 1 min!